# How can I figure out the full list of camping options in a given state?

Tags: usa, camping

Camping season is coming up in the US and I'd like to head out camping. I'm planning to stay in Washington and Oregon but flying to other states is not out of the question. Is there a resource that would show me 100% of possible camping locations in a given state, including county, state, federal and private campsites? Ideally it should also include a map showing locations open to dispersed camping.

Comment: AAA (the American Automobile Association) used to publish a CampBook for each region of the US, which was a pretty comprehensive list of developed campgrounds, both public and private (wouldn't show dispersed camping though), and available for free to members on request.  For some states they also had a large paper map.  I don't know the current status of this, but if you or some friend is a AAA member, you could check into it.

Comment: Unlikely that a single source exists. For example, dispersed camping is (generally, but not always!) allowed on BLM land and there is a ton of BLM land in eastern Oregon and Washington. Similarly, National Forests often allow dispersed camping and the details are usually found on their MVUM (motor vehicle use map).